# I want to automatically add the bundle product to the cart

Tags: magento2

Simple products are added to cart and everything is fine, but bundle products are not added to the basket.

```
 $params = array(
                    'product' => $products_id,
                    'qty' => $products_count
                );
                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById( $products_id );
                $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                $this->_cart->save();
```

give an error , 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please specify product option(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
$data = [
       'qty' => 1, 

         'product' => 8,

         'bundle_option' => [

             3 => 12,  Option ID => Selection ID

          ],

          'bundle_option_qty' => [

               3 => 1,  Option ID => ordered quantity of this option

           ]

          ];

          $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById( $products_id );

          $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

add the required options to your params array

```
$params = array(
                    'product' => $products_id,
                    'qty' => $products_count,
                    'options' => array(
                        'attribute_code' => 'value'
                     ),
                );
                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById( $products_id );
                $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                $this->_cart->save();
```